# Como proceder em casos que falta Tag em pergunta

Tags: debate

Em algumas vezes percebo que a pessoa que faz a pergunta acaba não colocando alguma Tag bem importante, como nesta pergunta [Mapear composite IDS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44801/ajuda-com-mapeamento-de-composite-ids-hibernate-2) onde acredito que deva constar a Tag Java.

Entretanto, fora a falta da tag a pergunta parece bem formatada e formulada, assim sendo não tem mais o que alterar nela.

Neste caso como devemos fazer para acrescentar a tag se não é aceito edição < 6 caracteres?

Comment: Você tentou só colocar a tag e o sistema reclamou?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim

Comment: Será que a funcionalidade "editar tags" possui requisito mínimo de reputação? Pois uma coisa é editar a pergunta e mexer só nas tags, outra é editar só as tags usando esse recurso. Por favor passe o mouse à direita da última tag e veja se esse link aparece pra você ou não. P.S. Acho que deve estar restrita a usuário com permissão de edição sem aprovação

Comment: @mgibsonbr para mim não existe essa opção de editar tags, deve estar restrita por reputação mesmo.

Comment: É, deve ser mesmo. Antigamente havia um privilégio só de edição de tags, mas acho que não existe mais.